# How can I do advanced filtering in Google Sheets?

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, scripting

**UPDATED AT END**

I have a Google Sheet I'm using to track television programs available to the PBS Station I work for.  (The link is for a copy of the first 30 rows rather than sharing the full sheet.)  Things I need to track and be able to search by are: Title, NOLA Code, Program/Series, Length (half hour increments), Topic, Secondary Topic, Aired (Yes/No), Server/Tape/sIX, Distributor.  I have other columns but rarely need to search content by them.

Originally I created a tab for each Topic I have listed and run a filter in an equation to populate the tab based on the master sheet but that's problematic if I find an error - I have to go back to the main sheet to correct it.  I find I'm using the Data/Filter View option on the main tab now to save jumping back and forth but it's limiting in that I often need to filter by multiple rows at the same time.

Ideally I would like to create a row for queries (row 2, in this example, would be where I would like to enter query information), and be able to enter data into the cell in each column of this row as needed, and run a script that will then filter each row based on whether it matches all the criteria I have entered - I made each cell I want to be able to filter on orange.  And then another script to revert back to an unfiltered sheet.

For example, I often have to look for all programs (not series) that are 30 minutes with a certain topic so I run a Filter View on the Length column, but still have to look through the resulting list to find everything that matches the other 2 criteria I'm looking for.  There has to be an easier way.  The full database is almost 1300 rows and is growing faster than I'm taking old content out so each search is taking longer and it's getting frustrating.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TIelXfkJ46NkjcPDTG_seLKR-fqKO5tn3R-OI5p984k/edit?usp=sharing

**update**

So, I've gotten the method that commented about to *mostly* work.  I get an error saying the equation expected a "(" if the search criteria in P2 is empty, but if it's filled in I get the expected results.  I don't understand the "(" error? I have updated my sample sheet to show this in the Search Engine tab.  It uses the following formula to query.

```
=QUERY(Programs!A2:AG, 
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" "&A2&" ", 1, 
 IF(B2<>"", " B='"&B2&"'", ), 
 IF(C2<>"", " C='"&C2&"'", ), 
 IF(E2<>"", " E='"&E2&"'", ), 
 IF(F2<>"", " F='"&F2&"'", ), 
 IF(G2<>"", " G='"&G2&"'", ), 
 IF(H2<>"", " H='"&H2&"'", ), 
 IF(I2<>"", " I='"&I2&"'", ), 
 IF(O2<>"", " O='"&O2&"'", ), 
 IF(P2<>"", " P='"&P2&"'")))
```

Ideally I would like something similar to this but which runs on the Programs tab so I could edit entries directly rather than bouncing back and forth between tabs if I need to make a change.

Comment: would something like this satisfy you? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579141/5632629 or you want to go full script mode?

Comment: This looks like what I need.  I'll see if I can get it to work for me tomorrow when I get in.  Thanks.

Comment: I have it mostly working and does what I need but I'm occasionally getting some random errors that I haven't been able to figure out yet.  If I can't get it figured out tomorrow I may post a follow up - at this point I haven't figured out what search criteria is even causing the error.

Comment: Actually, I realize this doesn't meet my needs because it uses a separate tab to show the data which means I can't edit at the same time I'm looking at results.  It's better than my previous attempts but it would be best if it all happened in the same tab as my data.

Comment: It was missing a "," not a "(", the separate tab search engine now works like it should!  I do still have my question about running something like this on my main tab.